# How to write a short XML end tag instead of a long end tag?

Tags: xml, vb.net, attributes, element

Excuse my ignorance but I'm just starting at VB and here is my basic doubt. I've searched a lot but I can't find the solution. I'm using this code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

  Private Sub saveXML_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveXML.Click
    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True

    Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("MyName.xml", settings)

    With XmlWrt
        .WriteStartDocument()
        .WriteComment("XML Database.")
        .WriteStartElement("Production")
        .WriteStartElement("Order")
        .WriteStartElement("Attribute")
        .WriteAttributeString("Type", "Order ID")
        .WriteAttributeString("Value", txtFullName.Text.ToString())
        .WriteFullEndElement()
        .WriteStartElement("Email")
        .WriteString(txtEmailAddress.Text.ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()
        .WriteStartElement("Tel")
        .WriteString(txtPhoneNumber.Text.ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()
        .WriteEndElement()
        .WriteEndDocument()
        .Close()
    End With

    MessageBox.Show("XML file saved.")
  End Sub
End Class
```

And with this part:

```
.WriteStartElement("Attribute")
.WriteAttributeString("Type", "Order ID")
.WriteAttributeString("Value", txtFullName.Text.ToString())
.WriteFullEndElement()
```

I get this:

```
<Attribute Type="Order ID" Value="5"></Attribute>
```

As you notice I don't type the `.WriteEndElement()` method in order to not show the end element tag:

```
</Attribute>
```

How can I write "/" and get this:

```
<Attribute Type="OrderId" Value="5"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`WriteEndElement()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeendelement(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`WriteFullEndElement()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writefullendelement(v=vs.110).aspx) to produce

```
<Attribute Type="Order ID" Value="5" />
```

instead of

```
<Attribute Type="Order ID" Value="5"></Attribute>.
```

---

But maybe you want to use XML literals, which makes it even easier:

```
Dim xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <Production> 
            <Order> 
                <Attribute Type="Order ID" Value=<%= txtFullName.Text %> /> 
                <Email><%= txtEmailAddress.Text%></Email> 
                <Tel><%= txtPhoneNumber.Text %></Tel> 
            </Order> 
            </Production> 

xml.Save("MyName.xml")
```

Comment: This answers OP question, but you also should also note that any receiving software that differentiates those two forms is broken and cannot claim to be processing XML as defined by the standard.